# dangling pointer issue in C vs variable scope

Tags: c, pointers

I know when we return local variable address to caller. It becomes dangling. To fix that, we need to use static. Here x goes out of scope, therefore the problem arises.

```
int *fun()
{
    // x is local variable and goes out of
    // scope after an execution of fun() is
    // over.
    int x = 5;

    return &x;
}


int main()
{
    int *p = fun();
    

    // p points to something which is not
    // valid anymore
    printf("%d", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

Why this is not an issue when we return the value of x instead of its address. In this case also value of x is local and in the caller value of p should be a garbage, as local variable x scope ends.

```
int fun()
{
    int x=5;
    return x;
}

main()
{
    int p;
    p = fun();
    printf("%d", p);
}
```

Comment: It's a copy of `x` that is returned to the caller and not `x` itself.

Comment: Things like this are best understood by looking at the assembly code. You can request the assembly from gcc or clang by using the `-S` option. On most processors, what you'll see is `fun()` puts 5 into a register, and `main` looks for the return value in that register.

Comment: 'To fix that, we need to use static' no,you really don't.  That's what the designers of strtok() thought...  Whatever the question is, 'static' is not the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C language functions receive and return copies of variables. So you don't have problem with local variable that does not exist - because you operate with copy of value of this variable.

Answer (score -2):

here's is the concept of memory comes into play. Your code memory has been divided into 3 segment, namely code block, heap and stack.
when every you call a function , the function local variable gets created an stored in stack and gets deleted automatically as soon as the function ends.
In your second code you have declared your variable p in main function, and it carries the value which is return by fun().A function only terminates when it throws some value, here in your code p as assigned the value returned by the fun before the function variable in stack block gets deleted.
here we are just using the copy of x variable which is assign to P before being deleted by the compiler.